# Linter that checks that all fields are explicitly set in struct initialisation

Tags: go, static-analysis

I want to have a static assert or linter for my go code that checks that I do not – by mistake – initialise the structs in my config file with *default values* for any field. I want everything to be set explicitly.

Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: Clarified question.

Comment: Nothing can inspect a struct and tell you if a field value was explicitly set to its zero value or if it was never set. The only way is to instrument the setting of those fields - e.g. pair every field with another `bool` field that you set to `true` when the accompanying field's value is set.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of a solution where the code is inspected warning the  programmer when errors are done. I don't know if this is common practice in the go culture but am very interested!

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/GaijinEntertainment/go-exhaustruct for it.

In `golangci-lint`, this linter is called `exhaustruct` and is disabled by default (see [documentation](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/#disabled-by-default)).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the validator package.
https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9

We use it extensively in our code to validate structs.
e.g.

```
type Config struct {
  Url      string  `validate:"required"`
  MaxHops  int     `validate:"omitempty,min=0"`
  MaxTerms int     `validate:"omitempty,min=0"`
  MaxCost  float64 `validate:"omitempty,min=0"`
}

func Init(cfg *Config) error {
  if err := validator.New().Struct(cfg); err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "error in config")
  }
  //do something
}
```

Comment: This won't tell you if a field value was explicitly set to its zero value or if it was never set.

Comment: thats true...for that case we sometimes resort to using pointer fields if its not a overkill.
e.g
` 
    type Config struct {
     Url      string  `validate:"required"`
    MaxHops  *int     `validate:"required"`
    }
`
But that again requires extra code to validate the pointee.

Comment: True, though that still won't catch, say, a JSON configuration that passes `null` to those fields. Any field can potentially be explicitly set to its zero value, and there is no way to know if that was the case from inspecting the field afterward.